# Ant - using variables in .properties files

Tags: ant

I am trying to replace placeholders in source files with values defined in a .properties file using the *copy* task with **

My build.xml contains

```
  <target name="configure">
    <echo message="Creating DB configuration" />
    <copy todir="${dir.out}" overwrite="true">
      <fileset dir="${dir.in}" />
      <filterchain>
        <expandproperties/>
        <replacetokens begintoken="&lt;" endtoken="&gt;" propertiesResource="conf.properties" />
      </filterchain>
    </copy>
  </target>
```

A sample from the conf.properties:

```
tbs.base_directory = d:/oracle/oradata/my_app
tbs.data_file = ${tbs.base_directory}/data01.dbf
```

I want to refer from within the .properties file to variables, in this case I would like to substitute *tbs.base_directory* in *tbs.data_file*.

Unfortunately it is not substituted. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that `expandproperties` applies to copied file not to the property resource you are using to define your tokens. A possible solution is to first load `conf.properties` to force properties expansion and dump it into a temporary file that is used for token substitution. Something like the following should work:

```
<target name="configure">
    <echo message="Creating DB configuration" />
    <!-- force expanding properties in tokens property file -->
    <loadproperties srcfile="conf.properties" />
    <!-- dump expanded properties in a temp file -->
    <echoproperties prefix="tbs" destfile="conf.expanded.properties"/>
    <copy todir="${dst.out}" overwrite="true">
          <fileset dir="${dir.in}" />
          <filterchain>
              <expandproperties/>
            <!-- use temporary file for token substitution -->
            <replacetokens begintoken="&lt;" endtoken="&gt;" propertiesResource="conf.expanded.properties" />
          </filterchain>
    </copy>
    <!-- delete temp file (optinal)-->
    <delete file="conf.expanded.properties"/>
</target>
```

Drawback of this solution is that it only works as long as you can select the properties to write in the temporary file (i.e all properties in the `conf.properties` file starts with the same prefix).